# Unix. Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a script it prints out a table for the rest of my project. My project is working fine however. When I use the script it prints out two errors along with the gui interface. I dont have the banner command or sudo (to install) to use those graphic interfaces.

```
#!/bin/bash


Welcome()
{
echo
"
|--------------------------
|          Red Hat         |
|     Enterprise Linux     |
|                          |
|    Server Release 5.3    |
|     Codename Tikanga     |
----------------------------
"
}

Welcome
```

However it prints out this

```
working: line 129:

    |--------------------------
    |          Red Hat         |
    |     Enterprise Linux     |
    |                          |
    |    Server Release 5.3    |
    |     Codename Tikanga     |
    ----------------------------

: command not found
```

instead of just

```
|--------------------------
|          Red Hat         |
|     Enterprise Linux     |
|                          |
|    Server Release 5.3    |
|     Codename Tikanga     |
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use:

```
echo '
|--------------------------
|          Red Hat         |
|     Enterprise Linux     |
|                          |
|    Server Release 5.3    |
|     Codename Tikanga     |
----------------------------'
```

Basically start quote after `echo` in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

In a shell script, a command ends with the end-of-line. So you have an

```
echo
```

which prints an empty line, followed by several lines of gibberish, which the shell tries to interpret as command, which it cannot find. Thus the error message (which is printed by the shell, not your script's `echo`).

(Wanted to edit in a solution at this point, but anubhava beat me to it. His solution works because the end-of-line is *inside* the string started by the `'`, so the whole string including newlines is interpreted as part of the `echo` command.)